# react-native start command taking forever in Windows

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I am trying to setup development for Android with React Native on Windows. I followed the instructions on the [Linux and Windows Support](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html#content) page to increase the time limit to avoid `ERROR Watcher took too long to load` error. The error went away but now when i run the command `react-native start` it doesn't seem to come to an end. This is how it looks (for hours).

```
    C:\Users\Interbiz\react\ProjectZ>react-native start
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐

 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │

 │                                                                            │

 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │

 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │

 │  prefer.                                                                   │

 │                                                                            │

 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │

 │                                                                            │

 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   C:\Users\Interbiz\react\ProjectZ

[2:03:38 PM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[2:03:38 PM] <START> Crawling File System
[2:03:38 PM] <START> Loading bundles layout
[2:03:38 PM] <END>   Loading bundles layout (2ms)

React packager ready.

[2:04:33 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (55585ms)
[2:04:33 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[2:04:39 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (5766ms)
[2:04:39 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[2:04:44 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (5344ms)
[2:04:44 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
[2:04:46 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[2:04:47 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (851ms)
[2:04:49 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (4577ms)
[2:04:49 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (71286ms)
```

Help me out here. And speak slowly please.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine. Keep it running, an in a separate console run "react-native run-android"